# getResourceAsStream(): how is decided where to search first?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, directory, bufferedimage

Imagine the following folder structure

- folder

  - App.jar
  - img (actually I didn't know it was there)

Inside the App.jar there is also `img` folder.

So I have used the following code to read an image img

```
InputStream is = IconManager.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("img/1.png");
BufferedImage bimage = ImageIO.read(is);
is.close();
```

I have knew before that this snippet worked perfectly for reading files from jar itself. But since by chance there was outdated version of img inside `folder` it started reading image files from from external `img` : folder/img and not jar itself. And I have spend much time to figure it out.

**My question is why the snippet by default try to read from folder/img and not App.jar?**

UPD: I run it using `java -jar App.jar` from `folder`

I use windows 7 and never specified `classpath` in Eclipse before building the jar

Comment: change the order of your items in classpath

Comment: I believe the order to search is basically down to your `ClassLoader`. It could choose to use the folder because it was listed first on the classpath, or for some other reason entirely. It's also possible there is a `ClassLoader` for the App.jar that's configured to use the "parent-first" strategy (though this is more likely to happen in a server environment like jboss or something), meaning it will first ask its parent `ClassLoader` to find the resource, before checking its own classpath. Maybe someone can confirm it/correct me.

Comment: @hoaz, I don't specify any classpath, I build jar from Eclipse

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov That just means Eclipse specifies the classpath for you and you can still change the order.

Comment: yes, but when you run it, you specify classpath, if you run it from eclipse, there is a tab that defines order of jars/projects (Run Configurations / Your target / Classpath)

Comment: @hoaz, @Thor84no, I run it only using `java -jar App.jar`

Comment: then check manifest in jar file, it contains classpath, also check project properties / java build path / order and export

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov From the command line rather than from Eclipse? Do you have a classpath in your environment variables? (I'm not sure which OS you're on)

Comment: @hoaz, yes I run it only from command line under Windows 7. Manifest from jar says `Class-Path: .`

Comment: if you remove this line it will use JAR resources only

Comment: @hoaz, so if I want to force jar file search img first inside itself how to I configure it in Eclipse before Export - Executable Jar?

Comment: if you have only one project, then i suggest you to extract manifest from JAR file, edit it the way you want and put it into your project, then specify this manifest file in export jar dialog and eclipse will include it instead of generating default one